# How to spawn the Killer Bunny?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I saw that there is a Killer Bunny that attacks mobs/players. **How to spawn it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the `RabbitType` tag to 99 will cause the rabbit to be a killer rabbit:

```
/summon Rabbit ~ ~1 ~ {RabbitType:99}
```

Comment: Why have you typed "1" after "~"?

Comment: @John The `~1` spawns the rabbit one block up form the executer. I imagine it was included so that, if you choose to put the command in a command block, the rabbit wouldn't spawn inside the command block and start suffocating.